# Request body missing from POST requests made using Postman scripting

Tags: api

I am trying to run a pre-request script for authenticating all my requests to the Spotify API. It works via the Postman GUI, but when I try to make the request via scripting, it fails because there is no body. Here is my code

```
    const postRequest = {
    url: pm.environment.get("spotifyAuthApi"),
    method: "POST",
    header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Length": 29,
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(pm.environment.get("client_id") + pm.environment.get("client_secret")) 
    },
    body: { 
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
    }
}
```

I get a

```
error: "unsupported_grant_type"
error_description: "grant_type parameter is missing"
```

And when I examine the request via the postman console, there is no request body, even though the request was built exactly like my fetch token request that does the same thing successfully in postman, only via the GUI instead of via a pre-request script. I have searched far and wide about this issue and tried multiple variations of the body object but to no avail. Either the body object doesn't generate my desired field, or it doesn't get created at all.

Answer (score 0):

Mode might be missing in the body object. Try this:

```js
body: {
  mode: 'raw',
  raw: JSON.stringify({ grant_type: 'client_credentials' })
}
```

More details might be found in Postman docs for [RequestBody](https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/RequestBody.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using urlencoded, the body of the request would be structured like this:

```js
body: {
    mode: 'urlencoded',
    urlencoded: [
        { key: 'grant_type', value: 'client_credentials'}
    ]
}
```